# Enable/disable a menu item if projects do/not exist in workspace

Tags: xml, eclipse, menuitem

I want to enable/disable a menu item, which uses the handler below, depending on whether there are any projects in the workspace.

But the following code doesn't work correctly. It enables/disables if a project is selected in the Project Explorer view. I'm not interested in selection, simply whether projects exist or not in the workspace.

```
<extension
  point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler
      commandId="sampleplugin.commands.sampleCommand"
        class="com.xxx">
          <enabledWhen>
            <iterate ifEmpty="true">
                  <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                    <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" value="org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature"/>
              </adapt> 
                </iterate>
          </enabledWhen>
    </handler>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to use your own property tester to define your own `<test>` using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point. The definition would be something like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
  <propertyTester
        class="package.MyPropertyTester"
        id="id.myPropertyTester"
        namespace="namespace"
        properties="test"
        type="java.lang.Object">
  </propertyTester>
</extension>
```

and the tester code:

```java
public class MyPropertyTester extends PropertyTester
{
  @Override
  public boolean test(final Object receiver, final String property, final Object [] args, final Object expectedValue)
  {
    IProject [] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();

    // Look for project nature

    for (IProject project : projects)
     { 
       if (project.hasNature("org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature"))
         return true;
     }

    return false;
  }
}
```

... 
And using the property tester in the handler like this:

```xml
<extension
  point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler
      commandId="sampleplugin.commands.sampleCommand"
        class="com.xxx">
                <enabledWhen>
                    <test
           forcePluginActivation="true"
           property="namespace.test"/>
                </enabledWhen>
    </handler>
</extension>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks, that works. I've updated your answer to show how to use the property tester in the handler.